# How convert String to dateTime with milliseconds

Tags: java, date

How convert this string to dateTime?

```
2016-01-09 21:04:56.0
```

I tried

```
private Date getDate(CallDetail callDetail) {
        Date date = null;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            date = simpleDateFormat.parse(callDetail.getStarttime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

But I have error:

```
Unparseable date: "2016-01-09 21:04:56.0"
```

I do not know how trim `.0`

Comment: your input date string & `DateFormat` pattern look nothing alike...

Comment: is the `.0` the format for milliseconds, or what is it used for?

Comment: "*moilliseconds*" is something new )

Comment: is not no need millisecond how to remove them?

Comment: well, you could simply include `.S` in the end of your format, but in order to make this whole thing work your inputformat and the format that the parser does expect should be equal...

Answer (score 2):

Your format string has to represent the string you want to parse.

E.g. if you want to parse `25.12.2015` your format string has to be `"dd.MM.yyyy"`.

With that being said, your format string to parse the given date should be `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:S"`

---

If you just want to get rid of the milliseconds you could either parse the date and format it it afterwards:

```
String toParse = "2016-01-09 21:04:56.0";
SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
Date newDate = sdfIn.parse(toParse);
SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
toParse = sdfOut.format(newDate);
```

or just cut off the milliseconds with `substring()`:

```
String toParse = "2016-01-09 21:04:56.0";
toParse = toParse = toParse.substring(0, toParse.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: I have String 2016-01-09 21:04:56.0 but I want get date 2016-01-09 21:04:56

Answer (score 0):

Try using below format `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse("2016-01-09 21:04:56.0");
        System.out.println(date);
    }
```

**output**

```
Sat Jan 09 21:04:56 IST 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern way is with the java.time classes and standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines many formats for representing date-time values as text. For a date with time-of-day, the format is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.s.

The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing and generating strings.

Your input string can be made to comply easily. Replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2016-01-09 21:04:56.0".replace( " " , "T" );
```

## `LocalDateTime`

Your input string lacks any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input );
```

Your goal seems to be generating a string of this date-time value without the fractional second if zero. The `LocalDateTime` class does this by default, printing zero, three, six, or nine digits of fractional second, the least needed.

```
String output = ldt.toString();
```

> 2016-01-09T21:04:56

For your desired format, replace the `T` with a SPACE.

```
String output2 = output.replace( "T" , " " );
```

A `LocalDateTime` intentionally lacks any time zone. As such, it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline. That requires the context of a time zone.

### Truncation

If you want to get rid of the fractional second, truncate.

```
LocalDateTime ldtTruncated = ldt.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS );
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).